# How to convert a String into a Function call in Swift

Tags: swift

I am writing a little app which I would like to use as a calculator. For the operators of the calculator I started with a switch statement to e.g. multiply two values. Therefore I created a dictionary and it worked fine.

I now found it would be quite useful and code saving if I'd write something like

```
number1 operationButton.currentTitle number2
```

where `operationButton.currentTitle` would represent `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`.

My question now is how can I convert the string of `operationButton.currentTitle` into a function call for these operators?

Comment: You should not rely on the button titles to have certain values (such as "+"). What if the title is changed to "add" later? – Better connect different actions to each button.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift, you can treat functions like variables - for example, you can store them in dictionaries.  Also, operators in Swift are just functions with non-alphabetic names (and that can be used infix etc.).

This means you can store binary operations in a dictionary:

```
let operators: [String:(Double,Double)->Double] = [
    "plus":     (+),
    "minus":    (-),
    "divide":   (/),
    "multiply": (*),
]
```

And then look up those operations and use whichever one you get, like so:

```
if let op = operators["divide"] {
    op(3,4)  // returns 0.75
}
```

Comment: That's correct and nice – but in this concrete case, relying on the button *titles* (which may be different in different localizations) in order to determine which operation to perform seems a bad idea to me.

Comment: Then again, some hybrid of the two is possibly appropriate if you want to be able to configure what the buttons do at runtime

Answer (score 4):

You should not rely on the button titles to have certain values in order
to decide which operation to perform. What if `+` is changed to `add`
later? And then localized to a different language? Or the button has no
title at all, only a fancy image?

Better connect different actions to each button, such as

```
@IBAction func addAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // add operands ...
}

@IBAction func subtractAction(sender: UIButton) {
    // subtract operands ...
}
```

Note also that different operators require may require different
error handling, e.g. the `divideAction` would check if the
denominator is zero.

Comment: This is not an answer —a suggestion at best.

Comment: @VatsalManot: If you think so ... I think it shows a way towards a better solution of the problem.

Comment: @VatsalManot: It could well be that the question is a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and if you read it as "how do I translate a button click into the math operation" then it *is* an answer.

Comment: Wow, had no idea what an XY problem was! Could you add a dummy edit? Because I can't change my vote.